# Clojure: Manipulating certain items in list

Tags: clojure

I'm a Clojure newbie and having trouble with its immutable state. I'm trying to write a function that takes a list with the frames of a bowling game. For example, a list would look like ["X" "12" "2/" "X" "45" "X" "13" "33" "X" "81"]. I want the function to output a list that takes care of the frames that just have integers, and adds the numbers together. So, if the list above was inputted, the following list would be outputted: ["X" "3" "2/" "X" "9" "X" "4" "6" "X" "9"]. This was my attempt, but immutable state in Clojure is making it hard for me to understand how to go about this:

```
(defn eval-frames
  [flist]
  (loop [frames '()]
        (if (not (= flist '()))
            frames
            (eval-normal (rest flist)))
        (if (not (or (spare? flist) (strike? flist) (= flist ())))
            (conj frames (+ (get (first flist) 0) ((get (first flist) 1))))
            (conj frames (first flist)))
  )
)
```

This just ends up outputting the first frame in the list, instead of the entire list. Any suggestions would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fair amount wrong with the code you posted:

- The whole `(if (not (= flist '()))` part does nothing since you never use the results it gives back. You're thinking too imperative here. `conj` returns the "modified" list, it doesn't alter the original!
- You never `recur` in the `loop`, so the `loop` only ever runs once.

I'd just use `map` for this. It iterates over a list, and "transforms" each element based on a function. I ***highly*** recommend getting as used to `map` and `reduce` as you can, because you'll be using them constantly.

My plan was this:

- If all the characters in the frame are digits, sum the frame, else, leave the frame alone.
- To sum the frame, I'm using `parseLong` to turn each character into a number, then`(apply +` to sum the parsed numbers, and then `str` to turn it back into a String.

---

```
(map
  (fn [frame]
    ; Almost reads like English!
    (if (every? #(Character/isDigit %) frame)
      (->> frame ; Take the frame...
        (map #(Long/parseLong (str %))) ; parse each character in the frame...
        (apply +) ; then sum the parsed numbers...
        (str)) ; and turn them back into a string.

      frame)) ; Else, do nothing and leave the frame alone

  ["X" "12" "2/" "X" "45" "X" "13" "33" "X" "81"])

=> ("X" "3" "2/" "X" "9" "X" "4" "6" "X" "9")
```

This would have been simplified a bit if you had stored the scores as numbers originally instead of converting them to Strings. That would prevent the need for `Long/parseLong`, and the final call to `str` to turn each summed frame back into a String.

Comment: And if for some reason you don't want to drop into Java interop, you can write your own "is digit" function.     (defn char-is-a-digit? [c] (<= (int \0) (int c) (int \9)))

Comment: @Markc You could. For minimal uses like this though, I don't see any problem. It forces using a wrapper function, but with the macro, that hardly adds any bulk.

Answer (score 1):

```
(map #(if (every? (fn [c] (<= (int \0) (int c) (int \9))) %)
        (str (apply + (map read-string (map str %))))
        %)
     ["X" "12" "2/" "X" "45" "X" "13" "33" "X" "81"])
```

or without the read-string:

```
(map #(if (every? (fn [c] (<= (int \0) (int c) (int \9))) %)
        (str (apply + (map (fn [c] (- (int c) (int \0))) %)))
        %)
     ["X" "12" "2/" "X" "45" "X" "13" "33" "X" "81"])
```

=> ("X" "3" "2/" "X" "9" "X" "4" "6" "X" "9")

Comment: Idk if I'd be encouraging use of `read-string` when `parseInt` suffices. Not the end of the world, but you might as well avoid `eval` behavior when you can.

Comment: Actually, it seems I stand corrected. I thought I had read that it immediately evaluates a string as code, but it seems to just parse code into a list of symbols. I still think `parseInt` should be preferred though, since bad user input may return a list instead of raising an error, or could cause an EOF Runtime Exception if they enter only a opening brace. It allows for much more to go wrong, whereas `parse-` functions will just return a NumberFormatException.

Comment: Good points. Nothing wrong with Java interop, but sometimes I avoid it so I can also use the code as ClojureScript.  Using read-string wasn't ideal, but it was shorter and cleaner. I've added yet another option that avoids read-string too.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn eval-frames [frames]
  (map #(if (re-find #"\d\d" %) 
    (reduce + (map (fn [i](Integer. (str i))) (seq %))) %) frames))
```

So evaluating with a given frame would give :

```
(eval-frames ["X" "12" "2/" "X" "45" "X" "13" "33" "X" "81"])
=> ("X" "3" "2/" "X" "9" "X" "4" "6" "X" "9")
```